# Filtering Pandas PivotTable

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pivot-table

I'm trying to feed Pandas some data via a SQL query then save the pivoted results onto a .csv file. So far I have been successful.

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

query = """
        SELECT 
            dt,
            --Workstack, 
            GM, 
            COUNT(JOB_NUMBER)
        FROM MY_TABLE
        GROUP BY 
            dt, 
            --Workstack, 
            GM
"""

connection = cx_Oracle.connect("<My_Username>", "<My Password>", "<Database String>")
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)
piv = df.pivot(index='GM', columns='DT', values='COUNT')
print (piv.head())

piv.to_csv('''Workstack.csv''')
```

Now I wish to include the field "Workstack" used within the query variable and I also want to use pandas to filter on different strings with the field Workstack then paste them as different csv files or on the same Excel file. However, when I include Workstack within the query python gives me this error...

`ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Any ideas how I solve this? Eventually I want to use a python Excel module to paste pivot tables like the one above onto different cells and sheets.

Thanks **:)**

Comment: Try to reset the index before pivoting: df.reset_index().pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pivot_table` with aggregation function:

```
piv = df.pivot_table(index='GM', columns='DT', values='COUNT', aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: or groupby () ;)

Comment: Great thanks for the help! Is there anyway I can create more pivot tables by filtering on different "Workstack" values?

Comment: Yes, `df.query('Workstack == 5).pivot_table(index='GM', columns='DT', values='COUNT', aggfunc='sum')`.

Comment: Hi Scott for some reason this didnt work I had to use

`PivotTable = df.loc[df['ColumnName'] == "ValueinColumn"]`

Comment: @RyanDavies.  Good, you should have been able to use 'query' it is just a bit more readable than using boolean indexing like you are doing here.   If my solution helped you, would you mind [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

query = """SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE"""

print('Loading Query')

connection = cx_Oracle.connect("Username", "Password", "Data Connection")
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)

PivotTable = df.loc[df['ColumnName'] == "ValueinColumn"].pivot_table(index='SelectRows', columns='SelectColumns', values='SelectValues', aggfunc='SelectAggregation')

print ("Writing to Excel")

ExcelWorkbook = pd.ExcelWriter('Data.xlsx')
PivotTable.to_excel(ExcelWorkbook,  sheet_name='PivotTable', startrow=1)
ExcelWorkbook.save()

print ("Closing Connection")
connection.close()

print('Section Complete')
```